# Separate auth sessions on same site with axios

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm trying to develop an app that logs into a website (through a form, so without any JTW or something). I must be able to log-in multiple users in the same browser instance with axios.
Example:

```
var userOne = FormLogin{
    username: 'usernameOne',
    password: 'passwordOne'
}

var userTwo = new FormLogin{
    username: 'usernameTwo',
    password: 'passwordTwo'
}

var userOneAuth = userOne.login();
var userTwoAuth = userTwo.login();

// In the same page
console.log(userOneAuth.info()); // Should output the info of the first user making a request with it's own authentication.
console.log(userOneAuth.info()); // Should output the info of the second user making a request with it's own authentication.

// This must happen in the same browser page
```

How I can achieve this with Axios (browser side)?

Comment: I don't really see why you need to use axios. Sessions are usually achieved using cookies. Just keep a list of session ids (or one session and the server keeps track of users) and you're good. Don't need to use axios for that.

Comment: Well, I must bundle all this inside an android application with Apache Cordova, and I cannot create any backend to handle this. Unfortunately the backend isn't written by me.

Comment: Then you first need to figure out how the site has implemented it's sessions. If it's cookies then you just need to manage the cookies.

Comment: It just uses ACCOUNT_SESSID cookie.

Comment: I assume axiom allows you to read the cookies yea? So you're all set.

Comment: Well, it's just this that I can't figure out how to do it. I just can't find any documentation of how to do it. I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: So the session cookie identifies the user. You log in twice to collect two session cookies. Then you use those cookies in whatever requests you want to do then. I'm not quite sure how to explain it. See it like this: you have a bag of lego bricks and you're asking how to build a house. You just build it. You don't need a book for that.

Comment: So the steps are: Login 1st user, grab cookie store in user instance, do the same thing with the 2nd. Then I can use it for each request related to the user. But the thing that I don't understand is: How can I do it with axios or any xhr js browser library?

Comment: XHR can't do it, you can only have one 'set' of cookies. If axios uses XHR under the hood then it also can't do it.